# Understanding crash log iPhone

Tags: swift, xcode, logging, runtime-error

I am a beginner developer, who tries his best. Currently I'm working on a complicated application, and everything works fine: expect one thing. 1 out of 100 times some basic thing crashes my app.

(This application is a Social posting app)

---

**1.** When I open a post to view it's comments, everything works fine. 99% of the time. But last time it crashed out of nowhere. I don't really understand.

**2.** The other time I opened the app after 1 hour no usage, and suddenly the app crashed.

Could someone help me out? Am I right with the following guesses?

First case:
**[Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/aUgRQDvv)**

> I think this is caused by **reloadSections:withRowAnimation:** . Am I correct?

Second case:
**[Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/k4eYe421)**

> And this is because of **performBatchUpdates** I call on a collection view. Right?

---

But I don't really understand where could be the problem's root.

**Here's my code, it looks completely harmless (for the second example):**

It's a collection view inside a tableCell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0 :
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoriesCell", for: indexPath) as! StoriesCell


            // Could use cell.storiesCollectionView.reloadData() too, but it flickers then
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: {
                cell.storiesCollectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                    cell.storiesCollectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(0...0))
                })
            })
            cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
            cell.collectionViewOffset = storedStoriesCollectionViewOffset[indexPath.row] ?? 0

            return cell
        case 2 :
        // ...
```

Comment: Why are you refreshing a cell while it's been constructed?

Comment: because the collection's data source is changing every 10 seconds, and if I don't reload it, it doesn't show the proper cells (with images)

Comment: so this UIView is inside the cell, right? This name is a bit ambiguous.
But I'd try to refresh the cells from tableView not from a cell itself and after the cells are created.

Comment: My app has a tableView full of post cells. But at the top (in section 0) it has a cell which contains a collectionView. I give it a try, thank you!

Comment: Or if that cell is totally different detach it from the tableView and put as stand-alone collectionView which you'll be refreshing every time tableVew data source is changing.